# problem with loader that lasts without an end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

*I added a 3 second mini load to my site with an animation . Appears every time I reload the site or go to another page*

---

*The problem is that as soon as I add the loading section, it never ends (it should last 3 seconds). Usually this endless loading happens to me when there is an error in the code, but I can't find it.
so I would like the upload section to last three seconds and not forever.*

---

***under I put the code with the loading section.***

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,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), auto;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style Base */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Header */
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.header__content {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1350px;
}

nav.menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu__internal li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 173px;
}

.menu__internal li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;

}

#Home-page {
  text-decoration: underline 2px #edba47;
}

.default {
  color: #fff;
}

.black ul li a {
  color: #000;
}

/* Hero */
.hero {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)),
    url('https://axisstudiosgroup.com/site/assets/files/11953/a0991_goodgame_empire_pk_20sec026_copy.-full.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* statistics */
.Statistiche {
  height: 100vh;
}


.loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 91, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 50, 104, 1) 100%) fixed;
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 91, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 50, 104, 1) 100%) fixed;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 91, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 50, 104, 1) 100%) fixed;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#005bb6', endColorstr='#003268', GradientType=1);
  background-color: #6D892E;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loader img {
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#rotator {
  font-size: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.4em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border: 0.03em solid white;
  border-right: transparent;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}

.loader.hidden {
  animation: fadeOut 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.thumb {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

  <!-- loaders -->
  <div class="loader hidden">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Goodgame_Studios_Logo_2015.svg/250px-Goodgame_Studios_Logo_2015.svg.png" alt="Loading..." />
    <div id="rotator"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__content">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu__internal">
          <li><a href="" id="Home-page">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Hero -->
  <section class="hero" data-midnight="default">
  </section>
```

***below I have unlike before, commented on the loading section, so you can see what's wrong.***

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,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), auto;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style Base */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Header */
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.header__content {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1350px;
}

nav.menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu__internal li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 173px;
}

.menu__internal li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;

}

#Home-page {
  text-decoration: underline 2px #edba47;
}

.default {
  color: #fff;
}

.black ul li a {
  color: #000;
}

/* Hero */
.hero {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)),
    url('https://axisstudiosgroup.com/site/assets/files/11953/a0991_goodgame_empire_pk_20sec026_copy.-full.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* statistics */
.Statistiche {
  height: 100vh;
}


.loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 91, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 50, 104, 1) 100%) fixed;
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 91, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 50, 104, 1) 100%) fixed;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 91, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 50, 104, 1) 100%) fixed;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#005bb6', endColorstr='#003268', GradientType=1);
  background-color: #6D892E;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loader img {
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#rotator {
  font-size: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.4em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border: 0.03em solid white;
  border-right: transparent;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}

.loader.hidden {
  animation: fadeOut 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.thumb {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

  <!-- loaders -->
<!--  <div class="loader">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Goodgame_Studios_Logo_2015.svg/250px-Goodgame_Studios_Logo_2015.svg.png" alt="Loading..." />
    <div id="rotator"></div>
  </div> -->

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__content">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu__internal">
          <li><a href="" id="Home-page">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Hero -->
  <section class="hero" data-midnight="default">
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JQuery like this?

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".loader").fadeOut(3000)
})
</script>
```

This makes the loader fade out for 3 seconds after the document is ready.

***If your site is dynamic you should try something different I guess.***

Comment: I solved it by putting

  `<div class="loader hidden">

  </div>`

-- the hidden class was missing

  `.loader.hidden {
  animation: fadeOut 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}`

@ardaravel